# How to add an byte value (8-bit) to string and read it back in byte in Java

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to develop an Android app, where I need to add an byte value (8-bit) inside a string and read it back again in byte[].

However I'm getting some different value when I convert the string to byte[] again using *getBytes()*. I think its some encoding or charset issue.

BTW I'm new to java programming I mostly code in C.

Code:

```
void function(void)
{   
    String a = "bla";
    char x = (0xD0 & 0xFF);  //Need to add & read back '0xD0'
    a += x;
    Log.d(TAG,"TEST: "+a);

    String mm = "-- ";
    byte[] buffer = null;
    try {
        buffer = a.getBytes("US-ASCII");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < buffer.length; i++) {
        mm+=" "+Integer.toHexString( buffer[i] );
    }

    Log.e(TAG, "Len:"+buffer.length+mm);
}
```

Output:

```
TEST: bla￐
Len:4--  62 6c 61 3f
```

Expected:

```
Len:4--  62 6c 61 d0
```

---

Found the solution:
Now I'm using encoding `UTF-16LE`, which does not loose data, and transmitting even bytes, skip odd bytes

**Solution:**

```
void function(void)
{   
    String a = "bla";
    char x = 0xD0;
    a += x;
    Log.d(TAG,"TEST: "+a);

    String mm = "-- ";
    byte[] buffer = null;
    try {
        buffer = a.getBytes("UTF-16LE");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < buffer.length; ) {
        mm += i +":"+Integer.toHexString( buffer[i] ) + ",";
        /* Skip odd bytes as using "UTF-16LE" encoding */
        i+=2;
    }

    Log.e(TAG, "Len:"+buffer.length+mm);
}
```

Result:

```
Len:8-- 0:62,2:6c,4:61,6:ffffffd0,
```

Comment: `byte`s are signed -128 to 127, `char`s are positive 0 to 65535.  You are probably adding `char` 0xFFD0 to your `String`, due to sign extension.

Comment: Yes but casting as `(byte)x` gives `Len:6--  62 6c 61 2d 34 38`, and by `and`ing with 0xff i am converting it to unsigned. I'm not getting how `3f` is getting there.

Comment: "0xD0 & 0xFF" is "0xD0".   "(byte)(0xD0 & 0xFF)" is -48.

Comment: Thanks, but without casting it gives error. And changing `byte` to `char` gives same result

Comment: What you are doing is inherently wrong.  Strings are not arrays of bytes; they are arrays of characters, which are 2 bytes.  Your getBytes() at the end is converting 2 byte characters into 1 byte ... well ... bytes.  There is a loss of information that occurs at that step, if characters are outside the US-ASCII range.  If you want to accumulate bytes, you should use a `ByteBuffer` or similar structure.  JSYK: Your buffer result `62 6c 61 2d 34 38` is `"bla-48"` ... the byte was converted to a string and appended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As java was created, they made a distinction between **binary data** (`byte[], InputStream, OutputStream`) and **Unicode text** (`String, char, Reader, Writer`). This means that `byte` is 8 bits and `char` is 16 bits, containing UTF-16. Now UTF-16 encodes Unicode text - where the characters ("code points") are numbered into the 3 byte range - in a format sometimes needing two 2-byte chars. All in all you cannot use arbitrary chars. And the implicit or explicit conversion always is costly.

Better use ByteArrayInputStream and ByteArrayOutputStream which can be used to collect a variable number of bytes and then retrieve the `byte[]`.

If still the wish exists, you can convert from a 1 byte encoding like ISO-8859-1.

```
String s = "blah\u00d0";
String s = "blah" + '\u00d0';
String s = "blah" + ((char)0x00d0); // < 0x100 still in safe range
byte[] b = s.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
s = new String(b, "ISO-8859-1");
```

The other difference with C is that `\u0000` is a normal character in a String.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
String s = "Hello";
s += (char)((byte)0xD0 & 0xFF);
```

`s == "HelloÐ"`

```
Integer.toHexString(s.charAt(s.length()-1) & 0xff) == "d0"
```

To specify encoding while getting the bytes you can do `s.getBytes("UTF-8");` if you need a specific encoding to send over the network or wherever

And you can create a new String from encoded bytes like this `String s = new String(utfByteArray, "UTF-8");`

Comment: Thanks, but I'm basically trying to get `D0` in byte[] array not `-48`, basically I need to transfer `D0` as single byte over serial port. I tried as you said but still getting `3f`

Comment: Just updated my answer (I'm new to this site idk if it tells you)